# ipywidgets Jupyter Notebook: select multiple checkboxes to filter the dataframe and plot it out

Tags: python, pandas, jupyter-notebook, interactive

Any good suggestions on how to build checkboxes to select certain groups of dataframe for visualization in jupyter notebook?

**Here's an example:**

```
>> df
    label value date
1   A     4     2021-10-10
2   B     2     2021-10-11
3   B     3     2021-10-11
4   A     5     2021-10-09
5   C     7     2021-10-10
6   A     2     2021-10-09
```

In this scenario, I intended to create three checkboxes for users to display what they want. If users click `A` and `B`, The program will display `df[df.isin('label':['A','B'])]` and say plotting out a stacked bar chart displaying the number of `A` and `B` in terms of `date`.

(Plotting part totally works, it's just the interactive part I haven't found a way to figure out)

**Here's my thoughts:**

```
from ipywidgets import Checkbox, interact

label = ['A', 'B', 'C']
ckb=[Checkbox(description=a) for a in label]

filtered_df=None

def checkbox_fig1(**kwargs):
    global filtered_df

    # Not sure for the following part
    selected=[]
    for k, v in kwargs.items():
        if k:
            selected.append(k)

    filtered_df = df1[df1.isin(selected)] 

interact(checkbox_fig1, **{c.description: True for c in ckb})
```

Overall it's displaying whatever I checked either one label or multiple labels.
I would really appreciate if anyone could offer some suggestions!!!

Comment: Not sure if plotly supports any features like that, but not that I know of :/

Comment: I would rather select the columns with an `if v` instead of `if k`...